# Scenekit Convert scene in obj file

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, collada

I am working with SceneKit for an iOS project. I want to export the current Scene into a OBJ file.

- Is it possible in Objective-C to create OBJ file with the SCNScene ?
- Is it possible to import OBJ file with Scenekit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's technically possible, yes. But there is no built-in API to do that if that's your question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. So only solution i got, is to build my own convertor ?

Comment: that or use an existing library that can convert between Collada and OBJ

Comment: Do you have an example, or some documentations to create my own ?

Comment: In fact, i can get the information of my obj from the SCNGeometry proprety. So maybe i can build my own obj file with that.